# Chrome bug on request audio tag source

Tags: html, google-chrome

Im trying to use an audio player on a web site, but when the file source is ".oga", the browser doesnt show the audio max length. In some cases, the browser requests the file indefinitely.

This bug only happens on Chrome (my version 112.0.5615.138).

in [codepen](https://codepen.io/luizctj/pen/yLRXyYg)

is there any way to fix that ?

```html
<div>
  <span>.OGA</span>
  <audio preload="auto" controls>
    <source src="https://filesamples.com/samples/audio/oga/sample2.oga" type="audio/ogg">
  </audio>
</div>

<div>
  <span>.MP3</span>
  <audio preload="auto" controls>
    <source src="https://file-examples.com/storage/fe21053bab6446bba9a0947/2017/11/file_example_MP3_5MG.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  </audio>
</div>

<div>
  <span>.OGG</span>
  <audio preload="auto" controls>
    <source src="https://file-examples.com/storage/fe21053bab6446bba9a0947/2017/11/file_example_OOG_5MG.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  </audio>
</div>
```